# youtube api for getting list of monetized vidoes

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like is to be able to search youtube for any given keyword or Channel, and for the results to show in a list basic information about the video, including video title, number of views, number of comments, when the video was posted and which videos are currently monetized. What I would then like to be able to do is create a list of all the monetized videos along with the URL's..

Can anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any documentations regarding your concern. I only checked on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) that you can only get a list of videos that match the API request parameters using `Videos: list`. You can only get `channelId`, `title`, `description`, `tags`, and `categoryId`. You may check this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95855/how-to-check-monetized-and-non-monetized-videos-from-my-youtube-channel) on how to check monetized and non-monetized videos from my YouTube channel. You may also read this [Monetization Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service) from YouTube.

Comment: I asked how to get monitized videos list via API not manually